# Shapefile disappeared after changing CRS

Tags: qgis

I change the coordinate system (CRS) of a point data but it disappeared. I tried zooming to layer but its not visible.
I am using QGIS 2.14

Comment: How did you change CRS? You should always change CRS by re-saving the layer. You can do this by right-clicking the layer and using the `Save As...` option. Or have you already tried this?

Comment: what did you change it from to?

Comment: This has happened to me a couple of times too. I believe some CRS interpret other CRS's values as literally off the charts resulting in them not being plotted anywhere. The feature remains snugly in the attribute table though, ready to be restored to the map using the correct CRS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way to change your CRS is to save the layer. Try the 'on the fly' transformation. Project>project properties> CRS> check the 'on the fly' transformation.

Tip: use always your default projection

Comment: "The correct way to change your CRS is to save the layer." - so why there is promising option "set layer CRS"? :)

Comment: @Line if your layer has a **wrong** projection assingned, you can correct it with "Set layer CRS".